# Javascript SELECT attribute's OPTION is not working inside any method

Tags: javascript, node.js, select, bootstrap-4

I am facing a strange problem. Please see my code clearly. 
While I am calling my following function in the root of my js file it is smoothly working.

```
    function setOptionValueWithNameAndOid(select, name, oid){
//here first parameter 'select' is my SELECT which is written in HTML and just pass the ID of that SELECT and 'name' and 'oid' is simple string  

        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", oid);
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(name);
        option.appendChild(textNode);
        select.appendChild(option); 
    }
```

if I call this function in the body of my js file like

```
setOptionValueWithNameAndOid(select, name, oid)
```

So this is perfectly working. Select option is adding. 
But problem occurs when I call this function inside any event or inside any function.

Please see this code carefully:

```
function loadNameOidSelect(url, select){
//here 'url' is my API url. and select is the same SELECT. just passing the id
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.onload = function() {

  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);


  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

    data.forEach(dta => {
       setOptionValueWithNameAndOid(select, dta.NAME, dta.OID); // from API i am getting 'name' and 'oid'
    });



  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
}



request.send();
}
```

but now problem is if I call the same method inside this api calling no option is adding in my SELECT. 
But If I call the same method in the page load with some static data it is perfectly working.

So can you please help me what actually problem?

Comment: Your comment says *just passing the id*, but your `setOptionValueWithNameAndOid` function expects an `HTMLSelectElement` object.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: I am also passing HTMLSelectElement.

Comment: No console error

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(this.response)` inside the callback? What is the output?

Comment: How do you call `loadNameOidSelect(url, select)` method? Are you calling it?

Comment: YES I am calling it inside

Comment: This is the response

[{"OID":"SCPxxxxxxxxx34","SCOMP_TEXT":"34","NAME":"ASGAR ALI HOSPITAL LTD"}]

Comment: Try to change `data.forEach` with `Array.prototype.forEach.call(data, dta => {
       setOptionValueWithNameAndOid // etc.`